# django - django-taggit - name 'TagFiled' is not defined

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms, django-views

I've installed `django-taggit` ( [click here](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit) ) and after install the package shows under the `python.2.7/dist-packages/taggit` along with my other packages.

In the `settings.py` I placed `taggit` under `INSTALLED_APPS`.

In my form I've imported taggit `forms.py` like this:

```
from taggit.forms import *
```

And my form looks something like this:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    my_tags = TagFiled()
```

My template is also pointing to that field like this:

```
{{ myform.my_tags }}
```

In `views.py` the form is instantiated this way:

```
myform = MyForm()
```

For some reason when I bring up the page containing the form I get this error:

```
name 'TagFiled' is not defined
```

Any ides what the problem might be? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it because you're misspelling `TagField`?

Comment: That's embarrassing but that was it :)